# Problemas al exportar la data a archivo csv

Tags: postgresql, csv

Tengo mi base de datos postgrSql de donde nececesito extraer mis datos a un archivo csv pero al momento de ejecutar el comando se me presenta el siguiente mensaje:

```
   ERROR:  no se pudo abrir el archivo «C:\Users\TECSINFO\Desktop\archivo\prueba.txt» para escritura: No such file or directory
********** Error **********

ERROR: no se pudo abrir el archivo «C:\Users\TECSINFO\Desktop\archivo\prueba.txt» para escritura: No such file or directory
SQL state: 58P01
```

A pesar de que el archivo si se encuentra creado en esa ruta, alguien que me pueda ayudar? Gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué comando estás ejecutando? ¿Puedes publicarlo? ¿Has comprobado que tu archivo no se llame diferente como `prueba.txt.txt`? Te recomendaría que pasaras por aquí si no lo has hecho y editar tu pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Saludos =)

Comment: Crea una nueva carpeta en disco `C` y ejecuta el comando apuntando a esa dirección `copy  mitabla to 'C:\carpeta\prueba.txt' delimiters ',';` y debería funcionar o creando la carpeta en otro disco local como _(D)_

Comment: He ejecutado el comando: `copy st_application to 'C:\carpeta\prueba.txt' delimiters ',';` pero el resultado sigue siendo el mismo.

Comment: he creado la carpeta en el disco C del servidor, ahí si funcionó. Gracias.